# Direct access to Askubuntu reputation statistics

Tags: support, reputation, statistics

I'd like to be informed (in real time) of changes in reputation, helpful flags, etc, for my user ID. I wrote a script that scrapes the reputation off my user page using `curl` and `grep`. That was the easy part, but other statistics appear to be generated by JavaScript. Is there any way of accessing these statistics without using a browser?

Ideally, I'd like to send a message to my mobile phone whenever anything changes.

Comment: Probably something in https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user might be useful.

Comment: Ah good, a whole API! Who knew. Thank you @muru, please convert this to an answer.

Comment: also have a look here http://askubuntu.com/reputation :)

Comment: Cool @Rinzwind - however, this page also requires authentication, so I need to go the Oauth2 way if I want to automate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange has an API to access user profiles: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user. I have never made use of it, so that's all I can say about it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed recently is that there is a widget in the [StackExchange Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en) that displays your current reputation:

[image]

Note this will probably use a bit of battery and internet data. I don't use anything like this on my phone much because of that *(also in this case I ain't to bothered about my reputation either :)*

Also note there is StackApplet [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484695/how-to-install-stack-applet) [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available/38052#38052), which seems to show your current rep (or something) in a drop-down menu:
[image]